# Confused about the output of floats and strings

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

float var = 15.4339;
char nam[9] = "chandler";

printf("%8.1lf\n",var);
printf("%-8.2f\n",var);
printf("%4s",nam);
printf("%4.1f\n",var+1.05);

return 0;
}
```

The output produced is:

```
     15.4
15.43
chandler16.5
```

I am quite confused regarding this output.
When outputting floats via printf using %a.bf, what does a do? Does it have any impact? Does it force a number with a+1 digits to be outputted as a number with just a digits by rounding it ?

Why is the first output offset? Does it output 8 characters of which 2 are the "15" with 6 free spaces?

Why does %4s output the whole array of char and not just 4 chars?

Comment: Take a look at [`man 3 printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

Comment: In %a.bf a is the minimum number of characters that will be printed before the decimal point.

Comment: This link might help. http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output

Comment: According to man 3 printf giving negative precision results in the precision being 0, is that the explanation for the extra spaces produced in outputting 15.4 as 8.1 ?

Comment: Shouldn't -8.2f output .43 if negative precisions are interpreted as 0?

Answer (score 1):

When outputting a float in C, "%a.bf" refers to the *minimum* number of characters to be printed before the decimal point (a) and the precision that will be used (b). "a" will either display the full number or pad it with leading spaces if it is shorter than the size specified (in this case, that is why your output is spaced out the way that it is). In the situation where you have a number with a+1 digits and attempt to print is using %a.xf, all a+1 digits will be displayed, as the number is not truncated, only padded to reach the size.

While on the discussion of padding widths, using the hyphen before the number (such as %-10.4f) will pad the end of the number with empty spaces. If you were to add text onto the end of that line, you would find that there are a number of spaces following the text.

%4s displays the entire string because again, it is only a minimum and as such does not truncate when the length is longer than you have specified.

As some example code to run, try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double testDouble = 9876.1234567;
    char testString[] = "Test string";

    printf("1: %f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("2: %2f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("3: %20f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("4: %-20f Example Text\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("5: %.0f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("6: %.3f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("7: %.4f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("8: %.30f\n" ,testDouble);
    printf("9: %s\n" ,testString);
    printf("10: %4s\n" ,testString);
    printf("11: %40s\n" ,testString);
    printf("12: %-40s Example Text\n" ,testString);
    return(0);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
1: 9876.123457
2: 9876.123457
3:          9876.123457
4: 9876.123457          Example Text
5: 9876
6: 9876.123
7: 9876.1235
8: 9876.123456699999200000000000000000
9: Test string
10: Test string
11:                              Test string
12: Test string                              Example Text
```

You can see how in 1, 2, 3 and 4, the number is never truncated, but it is padded up to the greater size if necessary.

In 5, 6, 7 and 8 you can see how the precision is formatted (the result is rounded in 7 and displays too many characters to be accurate in 8).

In 9, 10, 11 and 12, you see the formatting options as applied to strings.